# Google keep: reordering order of images with drag and drop

Tags: images, google-keep

I am wondering whether it is possible to reorder the order of Google keep images within a given note with drag and drop, from within keep.

It would be quite convenient, andI am wondering why this functionality is hot included or does not seem to be included in current versions of keep.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: As I understand it, Google Keep sorts like a stack: last in, first out.